# Where can I see Code execution time VS2019?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, runtime

Where in the VS2019 can I see the execution time of the code?
Sorry for stupid question

Comment: What version of VS2019 are you using?  Professional?  Student?  This may have an impact on your question as some useful features are only available in the more expensive versions of VS2019.

Comment: While you wait for an answer here, search the internet for "C++ benchmarking".  A lot of examples are not specific to VS2019 and can be used with any compiler.  Also search for "C++ profiling".

Comment: Also, are you using C++ or C# or Managed C++?  This will affect your answer, since some useful features of VS2019 only work with C#.

Comment: I use comunity VS,I use both c# and c++

Comment: @MariaKamenskyh,   Is there any update? If your question has been solved , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on the precision you're interested in. If *milliseconds* then in Visual Studio 2019 you can see the time between two breakpoints under **Diagnostic Tools** -> *Events* -> *Duration* (opens automatically in Debug mode, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

[image: VS2019 diagnostic tools events]

Some notes:

- Make sure to measure performance of the **Release** configuration. Debug build performance is meaningless.
- Make sure the code under test is not optimized away.
- If the code takes less than ~*100ms* to run, run it multiple times in a loop so that the measurement is on the order of 100ms or more, for better precision.
- I don't know about C#. I assume VS offers similar features for C#.

---

For a higher precision C++ code performance is measured in code itself using e.g. the [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) package.